# Magento 2 categories at layered navigation

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

In Magento 2 all the subcategories aren't showing in layered navigation. I am having categories structure for 4th level. If any 3rd categories having sub categories along with products - then it isn't showing at layered navigation.

Is there any settings available for same? Highlighted categories aren't showing in left from screenshot.[image]

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. U can go to stores-->configuration -->catalog --> category top navigation --> maximal depth (0= no limits).

Also if u use a custom mega menu or something they have also a setting for this

Comment: Above changes are already set. Its not working.

Comment: Which theme / mega menu extension do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Category.php` and update `_getItemsData()` function with below code:

```
protected function _getItemsData()
{
    /** @var \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $productCollection */
    $productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
    $optionsFacetedData = $productCollection->getFacetedData('category');
    $category = $this->dataProvider->getCategory();
    $categories = $category->getChildrenCategories();

    $collectionSize = $productCollection->getSize();

    if ($category->getIsActive()) {
        foreach ($categories as $category) { 
            $categoryManager = $this->categorys->load($category->getId())
                                ->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
                                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);

            if ($category->getIsActive() && $categoryManager->count()>0)
            {
                $this->itemDataBuilder->addItemData(
                    $this->escaper->escapeHtml($category->getName()),
                    $category->getId(),
                    $categoryManager->count()
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->itemDataBuilder->build();
}
```

I Hope this will help you.

Comment: when Im entering "echo 'In getItemsData'; exit;" at start of function then trying to use layered navigation, then execution not stop means its not calling that function then how it will work? Also I have replace core function with your function but result seems unchanged.